# Tool to measure all (js)objects in a webpage

Tags: javascript, browser, object, size

Is there any extension or tool to check size of Dom. Like firebug have Dom panel, which shows all events and functions declared in a web page, can this show more like size of the object, and in how many millis it gets loaded?

I'm looking for a tool to measure all (js)objects in a webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a tool that you can simply run yourself (like Google Chrome's analytic tools) or something you can deploy on your website?

If you just need the measurements, I'll recommend Google Chrome's Inspection window. Under "Profiles" a "Heap Snapshot" will give you an overview of all of the resources being used on the page, and how much memory is allocated to each.